# Java reference type

Tags: java

How does Java deal with passing reference data type arguments?? Can somebody give a clear picture?

Comment: Although Java uses references, the mechanism that it uses to pass "stuff" around is *"by value"*. See: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java passes a copy of the reference to the method.  The reference still points to the same instance.

Imagine if I had a slip of paper with a restaurant's address on it.  You also want to go to the same restaurant so I get a new slip of paper and copy the address of the restaurant on to that paper and give it to you.  Both slips of paper point to the same restaurant but they are separate *references* to the instance.

The restaurant itself is not duplicated, only the reference to it is duplicated.

Jon Skeet [provides a similar analogy](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html):

> **The balloon analogy**
>
> I imagine every
>   object as a helium balloon, every
>   reference as a piece of string, and
>   every variable as something which can
>   hold onto a piece of string. If the
>   reference is a null reference, that's
>   like having a piece of string without
>   anything attached to the end. If it's
>   a reference to a genuine object, it's
>   a piece of string tied onto the
>   balloon representing that object. When
>   a reference is copied (either for
>   variable assignment or as part of a
>   method call) it's as if another piece
>   of string is created attached to
>   whatever the first piece of string is
>   attached to. The actual piece of
>   string the variable (if any) is
>   holding onto doesn't go anywhere -
>   it's only copied.

Here is an example:

```
// Here I have one instance and one reference pointing to it
Object o = new Object();
// At this moment a copy of "o" is made and passed to "foo"
foo(o);

void foo(Object obj) {
    // In here I have obj which is a copy of whatever
    // reference was passed to me
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Can you give me a code example where this is happening?

Comment: I think your code example is a little misleading in the way it refers to a "copy" being made and passed to the method. The object in the method is the exact same object that was created and passed to it, and the comments in there don't make it sound like that.

Comment: @ColinD - While the instance is the same, the references are separate.  It truly is a copy of `o` that is passed to the method, `o` is the *reference* not the instance.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're saying and you are right... I'm just saying I thought that it would be easy to misinterpret.

Comment: Great analogy with the baloon!

Comment: I love that restaurant analogy. So much easier than the balloon :)

Comment: Ballon analogy also works well with describing garbage collection. I like it. +1

Answer (score 1):

All Java objects (everything except primitives such as `int`, `float`, `boolean`, etc...) *are* references to the pointed-to-object.

So for example:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

Above, `f` is a reference to an object of type `Foo`. If you then have a function:

```
void doSomething(Foo myFoo) { ... }

doSomething(f);
```

The `doSomething()` function receives the same object that `f` refers to. So if `doSomething()` mutates `f`, it is mutating that object.

Unlike C++, there is no choice between passing by value, reference or using pointers: All class-type variables are references (or pointer depending on your exact terminology).

One problem here is that people often try to apply their C++ knowledge and terminology to Java, which won't work.

Comment: Java is pass by value. Object references are passed by value.

Comment: As ColinD already mentioned: Java has but one mechanism to pass objects around: "by value". This answer might be interpreted that Java passes "by reference", which is incorrect. Note the "might be interpreted": I'm not sure you meant it like that.

Comment: But for all intents and purposes, variables of class type (in Java) always act like references. By your same logic, one could also say that C only supports pass-by-value. But we all know that C supports pointers, which lets you treat things like references. The problem is that you are trying to apply C++-style-language to Java, which isn't C++.